# How to fix the width of a minipage?

Tags: positioning, boxes, minipage

I put 2 `minipages` containing `tikzpicture` side by side: one on the left, the other one on the right. And I hope each `minipage`, surrounded by `\fbox`, occupies almost half side of the page, and leave some little space between them. I also want each `minipage` to have a `caption` and `label`. So now I could think of the following code:

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}%
\centering
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
picture1
\end{minipage}}
\captionof{figure}{picture1}\label{fig:picture1}
\end{minipage}\hfill

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}%
\centering
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
picture2
\end{minipage}}
\captionof{figure}{picture2}\label{fig:picture2}
\end{minipage}
```

However, the problem is the width of the frame or `minipage` is up to the width of the picture. I would like to fix that width, let's say around `0.48\linewidth`, but it seems that `\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}%` could not do that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem occurs because of the subtle length-management when using a `minipage` *within* a `minipage`. The **outer** `minipage` of width `0.48\linewidth` sets the line width within that `minipage` to `0.48\linewidth`. If the **inner** `minipage` is set to a width of `0.48\linewidth`, it is actually `0.2304` of the original `\linewidth`, since the nested `minipage` compounds the lengths. You also need to remove the spurious space after `\fbox{` by using `%`. Using this is better:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}%
\usepackage{calc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/calc
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry

​\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}%
  \centering
  \fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}% Remove fbox rule/sep width
      picture1
    \end{minipage}}
  \captionof{figure}{picture1}\label{fig:picture1}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}%
  \centering
  \fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}% Remove fbox rule/sep width
      picture2
    \end{minipage}}
  \captionof{figure}{picture2}\label{fig:picture2}
\end{minipage}
​\end{document}​​​​​​​
```

[image: Pictures framed inside minipages]

If you're interested in a vertical divider between the two images to visually separate them from one another, one could typeset the entire structure inside a `multicols` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}%
\usepackage{calc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/calc
\usepackage{multicol}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\renewcommand{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}% Columns are separated by rule of width 0.4pt
\begin{multicols}{2}% Two-column layout
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% No paragraph indent
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}%
    \fbox{%
      \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}% Remove fbox rule/sep width
        picture1
      \end{minipage}}
    \captionof{figure}{picture1}\label{fig:picture1}
  \end{minipage}
  
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}%
    \fbox{%
      \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}% Remove fbox rule/sep width
        picture2
      \end{minipage}}
    \captionof{figure}{picture2}\label{fig:picture2}
  \end{minipage}
\end{multicols}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image: Vertical line separating pictures]

The use of the [`calc` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/calc) is merely for calculation of lengths. And, the [`geometry` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) is used to highlight the page frame. Also, the [`lipsum` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) provides some dummy text.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i just run your code itself, why does it return 2 lines on the top of the page and 1 line on the bottom of the page?

Comment: OK, I see, it is the `showframe`...

Comment: @SoftTimur: Yes, this is the `geometry` package output when specifying the option `showframe`. It includes lines that distinguish between the header, footer, margin, etc.

Comment: By the way, what if I want to add a vertical line between these 2 pictures, just to show a separation. I have seen somebody doing it, but do not know how they realized that...

Comment: Just between the images, or also spanning to between the figure captions?

Comment: Well, that is not that important, let's say spanning to between the figure captions...